# Swift UIBarButtonItem Title

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

```
@IBAction
func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  guard let title = sender.currentTitle,
        let button = Buttons(rawValue: title) else { return }
}
```

The error I am getting says “Value of type ‘UIBarButtonItem’ has no member ‘currentTitle’, I have enums and cases for each button too.

Answer (score 0):

Try `gaurd let title = sender.title`

Comment: It worked! I thought I tried that at one point but that must’ve been on a different variation because now they register.  I voted up but my reputation score is still low, thanks for the help!